# What values should I use in package.json for the 'types' field?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, package.json

I am a noobie in the field of JS/TS and for learning purposes, I am creating an NPM package in TypeScript. Before building and pushing the artefacts to the registry, I compile the TS files to JS files using the `tsc` command.  Following is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "strict": true
    },
    "include": ["src/"],
    "exclude": [ "node_modules/", "tests/" ]
}
```

After compiling, the `dist` folder has the same directory structure as my `src` directory but it has all the `js` files and `.d.ts` files instead of `ts` files which is expected. My question is how do I include the `type definitions` files?

Googling this, I found that `package.json` file,  has a `types` field and to it, we assign the path to the `index.d.ts`, which in my case would be `dist/index.d.ts`. But it is not the only file that has type definions. There are many others in in many directories in the `dist` directory.

How do I include all those type definitions in the final artefact? I also tried assigning `dist/**/*.d.ts` to the `types` field in `package.json` but it didn't work.

I also want to know what is the right way of adding types to a TypeScript package.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to `export` all the useful types again in the index.ts so that they can be included in the `index.d.ts` eventually. I believe the `AWS SDK` did it this way.

For example, in `index.ts`:

> export { MyType, MyService, MyOption } from './other-file.ts';

So you can just put below in `package.json`

> "types": "dist/index.d.ts"